# Home Electrical AC Wiring Layout & Estimation Questions

Tags: wiring

I'm in the late planning stages of my retirement home, which I will be building in the rural Philippines. While I have no experience in construction, it's one of my 'bucket list' projects and I am determined to learn enough to at least supervise its proper construction.

I am now working on designing the layout for the AC wiring and have some questions for which I would be grateful for some expert guidance.

Specifically I'm thinking of running the wiring for the ac sockets in conduit, which will be embedded in the poured concrete floor slab. However, I plan to use a junction box to feed some of the sockets. Is it ok to embed these junction boxes? Would plastic junction boxes be ok to use?

Also, I have seen these convenient looking quick 'snap' wire connectors which can interconnect between 2-4,5 wires together. Are these reliable?

Lastly, in learning about wiring wall switches and lights it seems that the live/phase wire is mainly used to interconnect and power everything. The neutral and ground wires seem to connect the lights back to the DP. This being a reasonably accurate understanding(?), is there a general rule of thumb that can be used to estimate how much of each type/colour of wire to buy. For example, for a given length of live/phase brown colour wire purchased, one should buy 60% of that same length for the neutral (Blue colour) and ground (Y-G) wires?

Any experienced guidance would be much appreciated. Th

Comment: You should ask this in the Home Improvement area - there are many experts in home wiring there.  In any case, there should be an electrical code that will determine wiring standards in your area.

Comment: Theres a reason why in many (most?) countries, this stuff is checked by the government and requires a licensed electrician. Doing something wrong could result in an injury now, or an injury 5 years from now. I don't know anything about the phillipines building codes, but I would strongly suggest leaving most of this to a licensed electrician, and asking them these questions. Having knowledge is generally good, but some of the questions you're asking seem to be implying that you yourself will be specifying some parts of the system that really should be left to someone qualified.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. To clarify, I do plan on hiring a licensed electrician to do the actual work, but n the t that in the rural Phils, its a 'wild west' environment. Common practice is to use as little of the cheapest wire as possible. Most homes don't even ground their AC sockets! Also if you allow the electrician to buy the wire there are numerous horror stories where they charge you for the proper gauge wire but actually install thinner wire! That's why I'm trying to learn what is the 'proper' way to do things so I can ensure they don't just do a slapdash job. and also to buy the wire myself.

Comment: In that case, import an electrician you trust from somewhere that you trust the regulations, perhaps Austrailia. And then when finsihed, have a local simply sign them off.

Comment: In the US at least, you can not "bury" a junction box - Either in a wall or in concrete or wherever.  The box has to be accessible for future service.

Comment: Are you in USA-heritage center-grounded territory (120V each leg from ground, 2-pole breakers) or post-independence corner-ground Euro-style territory (1 wire near ground, the other wire 230V from ground)?

Comment: The Philippines seems to tolerate a mix of both US and Euro standards. In the rural areas however the utility feed is a 2 wire (hot, neutral)  230VAC drop. I plan to ground my DP to the rebar in the house foundation

Comment: You should likely throw down several grounding plates/rods under the foundation too.  Rebar in concrete won't give you a great ground.  PVC conduit is normal in concrete.  First thing is to choose an electrical code, either PEC, which is based on NEC, or the code of a country that exceeds it.One thing to do in concrete work is to run spare conduits here and there in case you lose one or want to add a feature later.  PVC conduit is cheap.  Think about features you might want to add later like a dedicated circuit for an A/V room or computer, or a network cable for the same.

Answer (score 3):

### Don't fall into the "neutral is ground" myth.

Electricity flows in loops.  It takes 2 wires on every circuit.

Hot AND neutral are the two partner wires that carry power to your appliances.  Expect to use them in roughly equal proportion.

You absolutely must not treat neutral as a "common/chassis/backplane" and simply have a bunch of circuits' hots share the same neutral.  That will set your neutral wire on fire.  Which, granted, won't do a whole lot in conduit inside concrete, but you will be forced to rewire at the least.

---

Safety ground is a totally different thing.  It is a safety shield.  Current never flows on ground (except during fault conditions, of course).

While it's true that neutral and ground are connected at the main panel, don't think they are somehow the same.  The purpose of the connection is to a) keep hot/neutral from floating at thousands of volts above ground, e.g. due to a transformer leak.  And b) current flows in loops, and that allows fault current that got on ground somehow, to loop back to neutral - and flow enough amps to trip the breaker.

It's possible to do isolated systems where H-N is not connected to G at all.  However that can cause problems.

Because of this, safety ground can be shared among multiple circuits (the ground wire must be large enough for the largest of the circuits sharing it).  As such, you need as much ground wire as you have conduit length.

If you use metal conduit -- wait, you can't use metal conduit in concrete! It will corrode.

As far as hot wires, they don't give out medals for saving wire.  Use as many hot wire colors as your country's electrical codes will allow - this will be very helpful when trying to distinguish one wire color from another.  I own 8 colors of hot myself and 2 of neutral.

---

You are not subject to the special case in about half of the Philippines (the legacy USA territories), where power is unusual. (two hots, each 120V from ground. Effectively, neutral does not exist in *those* territories, and this is a big bag of Not Your Problem.  Just be aware those territories do exist, and about half of Philippine advice will apply there.  So if you see stuff about 2-pole breakers and 2-pole switches, that is that, and doesn't apply to you.

Comment: Thank you. This advice is very helpful and appreciated. FYI, my design is to use separate N and G wires, but the wall switches  .... at least in this part of the world, don't use the N or G wires at all! The N wire is only connected to the (LED in my case) light fixtures which pretty much all use plastic housings, which don't have any (need for) ground wires nuts on them. From my research, in the US the light switches appear to be quite different, with L, N and G wires passing through them to the light fixtures.

Comment: @williamc The neutral will go through the _box_ but usually it is not _switched_ (no matter what the load is). The ground also goes through the box, and is attached to the switch as a safety. Only the hot leg of the circuit is actually switched, since, in most cases, this is all that's necessary. There are double-pole, double-throw switches that will break both H & N, but they're not needed in the US for _most_ residential wiring, and probably aren't needed for commercial lighting circuits.

Comment: @williamc Keep in mind there's a rule that says (in many more words) "Tree topology, never have circuits be laid out like loops", and "currents in a cable or conduit must balance". So in the US, if power comes to the switch first, neutral comes too, to balance.  Hot gets switched but neutral just passes thru.  If someone adds a smart switch later, neutral is conveniently there.

Comment: Now we also do "switch loops" where we bring always-hot and switched-hot to the switch, and neutral is not needed or used.  However we bring neutral *anyway* to accommodate future smart switches. I recommend you do the same.

Comment: Thanks. Your advice to 'balance' lighting circuits, seems to make intuitive  sense. I'm sure there are those who can provide a more scientific explanation, but your simple explanation appeals to my sense of symmetry.